# Can we have an auto-comment for the Off-topic flag

Tags: feature-request, flags, off-topic, automatic-comments

There are a lot of questions here on MSE that really deserve to be on any other "main" site in the network. They are usually met with a ferocious amount of downvotes, and usually closed (quickly).

Currently I see some dedicated users adding comments to these posts, to point out their mistake and guide these users in the right direction. A very noble cause, regarding be-nice and the welcome wagon campaigns.

**Example comment:**

> Hi [user], welcome to Meta! I'm not sure which search brought you here but the problem you describe will not be answered on this specific site. To get an answer from users that have the expertise about the topic of your question you'll have to find and then re-post on the [proper site](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Check [How do I ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and [What is on topic](/help/on-topic) on the *target* site to make sure your post is in good shape. Your question is definitely off-topic on [Meta](/help/whats-meta) and is better deleted here.

As I don't have any close voting privileges here on MSE I usually flag these questions as "Off-topic" -> "This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center."

***Can we have an auto-comment for cases like this?***

This will speed up the "welcoming" of new users, and give them more meaningful feedback then a load of downvotes, which culminate in a closure. Only after which any feedback is provided by the sites mechanics through the closure notice.

PS. We might need a dedicated closure reason to be able to implement this.

Answer (score 5):

Those comments you mentioned aren't typed by hand (luckily not), they're the result of the ['Saviour' of Lost Souls](https://stackapps.com/q/8122/34061) userscript. That script will also flag/vote to close/vote to delete/downvote the question (depending on your privileges and the state of the question). Since activating that script only takes two clicks, it's a decent workaround for me and for 6-8 other regulars here.

(The feature request is still useful (so +1) for users who don't want to rely on custom scripts, or even *can't* because of the browser – Safari on iOS comes to mind, or, as the OP mentions, because of company policy.)

Comment: I didn't expect them to be typed by hand, they are too abundant and consistent for that ;). Good point to "plug" this userscript!. One reason to add why people can't use it: because of company policy.

Comment: I use a varient of that comment with the pro forma comment userscript